# URL inserted at the end of URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I have a problem with url. I have an url `http://example.com/` but css not work because search in `http://example.com/example.comcss/...`

If I search a product directly insert: `http://example.com/category/product/example.com/`

Why insert path url at finish all time?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be that you configured the base url wrong. Make sure the base url in the system configuration always ends with a / (also check all configuration scopes like website and store).

Comment: Yes, in datatable I have `http://example.com/ `